# Gradle sync failed: Failed to create parent directory "path" when creating directory

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have a problem with my Gradle and Android Studio. I reinstalled Android studio and Im working with libGDX then when I try to compile my project, the terminal says me that.

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().
>     Could not create service of type CrossBuildFileHashCache using BuildSessionScopeServices.createCrossBuildFileHashCache().
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1s
>   Failed to create parent directory 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Android Studio.gradle' when creating directory 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Android Studio.gradle\4.0\fileHashes'

This error appear with this:

> 13:19:16: Executing task 'desktop:run'...
>
> Download https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.0-bin.zip (67.52M)
>   [ 97%] [ =====================================================> ] 66.07M
>
> Download https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.0-bin.zip succeeded, took 8s 734ms
>   Unzipping ...

My version of Gradle: 4.4

My version of Android Studio: 3.1.2

If you need more information said me to put that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. please try to run Android Studio as admin,
2. if no result try check and create the path manually

Bests )